# How to change a topnav and Update it?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

```
topNav.Navigation.TopNavigationBar[1].Title="Link Page Test" ;
```

Im doing it but no sucess:

```
SPWeb site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

SPNavigationNodeCollection topNav = site.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;

topNav.Navigation.TopNavigationBar[1].Title="Link pour Page Test" ;
topNav.Navigation.TopNavigationBar[1].Update();


site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
site.Update();
site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: are you sure for the index [1]? have you tried [0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this is what your looking for i think ;), from what i can see your trying to update from the node array collection. Instead you should be using `SPNavigationNode` loaded from the collection using `GetNodeByUrl` or `GetNodeById` instead and then update the node and web object rather than the collection!

```
     SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb

     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
     SPNavigationNodeCollection topNavNodes = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
     SPNavigationNode spNavNode = topNavNodes.Navigation.GetNodeByUrl("/Link Page Test");
     spNavNode.Title = "Link pour Page Test";
     spNavNode.Update();
     web.Update();
     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

if you dont like `GetNodeByUrl` and you know the id like you have done above you can use `GetNodeById`, more info found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation_members.aspx

id way

```
 SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb

 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
 SPNavigationNodeCollection topNavNodes = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
 SPNavigationNode spNavNode = topNavNodes.Navigation.GetNodeById(1);
 spNavNode.Title = "Link pour Page Test";
 spNavNode.Update();
 web.Update();
 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: no probs happy to help :)